# What are the advantages of using OFB (Output Feedback Mode)?

Tags: modes-of-operation, ofb, cfb

I have a problem with OFB mode, because I have heard that it is stronger than CFB.

Comment: What's your question?  Whether it is, in fact, stronger than CFB?

Answer (score 5):

> I have a problem with OFB mode, because I have heard that it is stronger than CFB.

On the contrary I would say that CFB is stronger.

OFB means encrypting the IV again and again to produce the keystream. If you end up in a cycle, the keystream [will start repeating itself](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27780/49923). (This should not be a practical weakness, but why chance it?)

CFB is more like CBC, in that it uses the ciphertext as input to the cipher for the next block. This means it will not enter cycles unless e.g. encrypting a constant plaintext. CFB can also recover from IV reuse if the plaintext it different (which is an advantage even over CTR).

> What are the advantages of using OFB (Output Feedback Mode)?

One advantage OFB *does* have over CFB is that you can pregenerate the keystream, since it does not depend on the plaintext. However, as the [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26709/13625) states, encryption with either algorithm is serial and cannot be parallelized. That makes CTR the best choice for performance, since it also allows keystream pregeneration.

Of course, in the real world you should just use an authenticated encryption mode (like GCM) unless you are certain you know what you are doing.

Comment: If you use GCM, CCM or EAX you would of course still be using CTR mode, even if that's not visible in the API :)

Answer (score 4):

Forget OFB mode. You should use CTR (counter) mode. It has the best bounds, and is parallelizable. This means that when you are using the AES-NI instruction set, encrypt with CTR is about 7 times faster than CBC, OFB etc. If you encrypt in OpenSSL you will get this performance.

For a good thorough analysis and comparison of modes of operation, see http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf.

Also, in most cases you should be using authenticated-encryption. If you're worried about the cost, GCM is 5-6 times faster than CBC/OFB on AES-NI. So, it's really very fast.

Comment: CBC and CFB decryption are parallelizable, so the speed advantage of CTR should only apply to encryption, not decryption.

Comment: This is of course true, and what I meant. I'll fix the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Could you add a reference for CTR having better security bounds?

Comment: I added a reference. Note that CTR is only better than CBC by 1/2. However, also note that if you consider the probability of distinguishing AES from a PRF (and not from a PRP) then the bound is much better. This is all explained in Rogaway's paper cited in the answer.